# ddwrt and wpa2 KRACK patch or update?

Tags: dd-wrt, wpa2

I have a ddwrt running on a TP-Link TL-WDR4300 v1.x. Build is `21061`.

First question is, if the build is already the version number of the ddwrt software?

And how can I make sure that the wpa_supplicant and hostapd patches are applied there? Or is there no patch available yet for ddwrt and `KRACK`?

Comment: As I understand it, the flaw being exploited has to do with the **client’s** role in the key handshake, not the AP’s. So it’s important to patch devices acting in client roles, not so much APs. Is your box acting as a Wi-Fi client?

Comment: DDwrt has already received a patch for this vulnerability but you have to compile from source.

Comment: https://m.windowscentral.com/vendors-who-have-patched-krack-wpa2-wi-fi-vulnerability?_ga=2.63127151.1519868037.1508199950-321992676.1499915898 in theory only the patched file would have to be replaced but **research** the advised approach by the ddwrt community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on a pretty old build for DDWRT. Download r33525 from 2017 betas folder. This one has the KRACK patch. The update was released on 17th October, 2017.

Link: http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/other-downloads

Comment: isnt there the risk of bricking my device with a beta? but stable is from 2008.....

Comment: I have been using these betas for a year now without issues. Infact, I had some problems with the stable version that seem to be gone with these recent betas. They haven't released a stable version for so long and these betas continue to provide performance optimizations, UI changes, tweaks and in this case the much needed security update.

Answer (score -1):

DD-WRT has released their patch. Visit their support website. You'll find there.